# Google BigQuery returns different results for the same query using python library vs BigQuery UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using a Django application that uses `bigquery.Client()` to query data using `query_parameters` notation (`@param`).

- When the query job is created using python and bigquery library, and we call the DB the result of the job contains results (**it should not**).
- In BigQuery UI I run exactly the same query replacing all the `query_parameters` for the proper value and the query does not return results (**as it should be!!**).

job_id_using_python = **8c39d0b0-54a7-4b0e-823c-ab49972e7563** (wrongly return results)

job_id_using_bigquery_ui = **bquxjob_7cfc79c5_18289e94ffd** (successfully return nothing)

I have no idea what's going on since I've been using the same approach to test, analyze my queries on the BigQuery UI and this is the first time that something like this happens.

Comment: Can you check on the "PROJECT HISTORY" tab (in BigQuery UI) what exactly query was running from python library? Maybe this query differs from a query you run in BigQuery UI.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but the jobs executed using the `bigquery` client are not showing data. it's just showing the record, the date created but it does not show query info. (maybe cause my IAM user does not have permission?).

but I'm taking the query text from the `query` attribute from the query job so it's the same query for sure!

Comment: Maybe row level security? If python client use service account with wider permission than your user, it can be that python client can get more data than you.
Read this: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/row-level-security-intro

Comment: Interesting, however It looks like that's not the issue cause I just made a simple `SELECT` to one of the rows returned by the python call, and It was possible to be called from the Big Query UI. :/

Comment: Can you share a sample code for Python and Bigquery UI query for us to replicate your scenario?